# Help Center on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-site

There is no link to the Help Center in the homepage in the mobile site, so mobile visitors cannot readily determine whether or not their question is appropriate.

A link should be added.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

With the recent removal of the dedicated mobile site in favour of a [responsive site design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/179041) catering to both mobile and desktop, you can now access the Help Center via a mobile device.